# Change EditText value when Fragment is restored from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have two Fragments: F1 and F2

F1 contains:

- an EditText that the user can fill
- a 'next' button to go to F2

When the user presses 'next', F2 is displayed and F1 is added to the backstack. So when the user presses back on F2 it returns to F1.

When the user goes back to F1 I want to reset the value in the EditText. As I want to reinitialised the value only when the view is recreated, I reset the value in the `onViewCreated` and not in `onResume`.

The problem I have is that the EditText is automatically filled by the system when the user presses back as it tries to restore the Fragment in its previous state.
The value is automatically repopulated in `onViewStateRestored` from the `saveInstanceState` bundle.

So my question is: is it a good idea to override the `onViewStateRestored` method to send a null bundle to super (see below), as it solves my issue?

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(null);
}
```

Comment: " I reset the value in the onViewCreated and not in onResume." Why doing this ? If you want to reset the value when F1 is shown you should reset the EditText in onPause() or onResume()

Comment: This is a very basic example but my project is more complex and I don't want to reset the entire UI on onResume as it's not necessary as it shouldn't have been changed as not destroyed. But I want the view to be reset when the UI is recreated from scratch (which happens only when the Fragment is restored from the backstack)

Comment: According to [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) your view is not destroyed when you open F2. The fragment is just stoped. So you should put your code in onStart() or onResume()

Comment: It is. If you have a look at `Figure 2. The lifecycle of a fragment` from your link, you can see that `onDestroyView` is called when the fragment is added to the backstack, and `onCreateView` is called again when restored. Btw this scheme is uncompleted as it doesn't show the call to `onViewStateRestored`. That's why I generally prefer [this one](https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/101826485820997153590/5914215085941005954) even if not from the official documentation

Comment: Interesting Scheme, thx for the link. According to it you seems right (I have to admit it, it hurts.. argh XD). Still I don't understand why you can't put your code in onStop() ? It seems to me that it's the right place since it's just after StateRestored(). So your view will be all restored and you just have to modify the ones you want to change.

Comment: Maybe your goal is to skip StateRestored body ? If it is then yes you should overwrite it to let it empty. But you should not initialize your view in as it is designed only to restore a saved state according to [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: I want to initialise the UI in `onViewCreated`, means only when the view is properly created. So yeah I want to override `onViewStateRestored` only to skip it. I don't want to write more in this method than in the sample above

Comment: @vincrichaud Wait, I'm actually wrong. It doesn't seem to work finally. When the fragment is restored from the backstack, `savedInstanceState` is already null. So when is the state of the EditText restored?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `onResume` as you suggested

Comment: I think it's initialized in [onViewCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated). The doc says you should override it to initialize yourself. So i think inside the default one it call a private function that restore the savedState.

Comment: @vincrichaud Yeah but if you override `onViewCreated` and call its parent first your code is still overridden by the system later. The safest way is to put your code after calling 'super' in `onViewStateRestored` as the documentation mentions: `Called when all saved state has been restored into the view hierarchy of the fragment.` 
But as this method is called only when the view is restored, it's better (as you said) to do it on `onResume`. So you're right too at the end ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is: is it a good idea to override the onViewStateRestored method to send a null bundle to super (see below), as it solves my issue?

The answer is most probably no. This kind of "small" hacks usually lead to huge WTFs and long debug sessions in the future.

For instance, if I'm not mistaken, this hack will immediately lead to a bug in context of config change and save&restore flows. Since in both these flows fragment's `View` will be re-created, you will loose user's input.

Most probably, that's not the behavior you want.

I read your discussion in the comments, and still can't understand why you insist to condition clearing of `EditText` on re-creation of fragment's `View`.

You want this `EditText` to be empty if the user gets back to this fragment, right? Then, IMHO, the best solution will be to clear it when "next" button is clicked before transitioning to F2.

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issues.

How I solved :

1. setSaveEnabled(false); for edit text.
2. Created a Singlton model class
3. Once I move to next fragment, save data in singlton model.
4. Set data on CreateView from model to edit text.

Might be there are some more optimized sol available so please guys suggest in comment.

Comment: Working for me Thanks!!