# Restore fragment's previous state on rotation and position in backstack

Tags: android, fragment, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I have an app with a single activity showing a fragment to the user. On a click on a button, the activity shows another fragment but keeping the previous one in the `backstack`. I have now two problems:

- On rotation (particularly in the second fragment), the data entered in the `EditTexts` is cleared
- I want the `backstack` to be also restored with the text previously entered in the second fragment.

The problem is that when I save data to bundle using `OnSaveInstanceState(...)`, I successfully get it again from `OnViewCreated(...)` but when I use `editText.setText(str)`, the text is not shown.

At the moment, I think this is because the fragment is then destroyed and recreated by the parent Activity.

How can I do to make it work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: I add the same [question the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49757603/1827254). Basically you need to use `onResume` to set the EditText value. If you set it in `onViewCreated` it's then overridden by the system as it tries to restore the previous state itself.

Comment: I'll try that, I'll tell you if it works for me!
How can I restore the backstack?

Answer (score 0):

Make your fragments retainable:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

See the following guideline on orientation change state [android orientation changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) `

Comment: That doesn't keep the backstack!

Comment: Okay then an idea would be to show and hide the fragments this keeps the backstack alive.

Comment: How is it possible to restore the backstack?